# How to handle MySqlConnector.MySqlException in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to report MySqlExceptions to my exception API but it seems to spit out the exception and continue execution somehow?

I have an unhandled exception handler setup, purposely made a bad query but it never gets hit it seems.

Any other exception type get reported, and execution stops until `Console.ReadKey()` gets passed, and then exits.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;

private static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    _bugsnagClient.Notify((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
    
    Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Code:

```
using var dbConnection = _databaseProvider.GetConnection();
dbConnection.SetQuery("INSERT INTO `profiles` (`url`,`provider_id`,`worker_id`, `media_count`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (@url,@providerId,@workerId,@mediaCount,@createdAt,@updatedAt);");
// @url,@providerId,@workerId,@mediaCount,@createdAt,@updatedAt)
dbConnection.AddParameter("url", profile.Url);
dbConnection.AddParameter("providerId", (int)profile.Provider);
dbConnection.AddParameter("workerId", profile.WorkerId);
dbConnection.AddParameter("mediaCount", profile.MediaItems.Count);
dbConnection.AddParameter("createdAt", createdTimestamp);
dbConnection.AddParameter("updatedAt", createdTimestamp);
await dbConnection.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Stacktrace (truncated):

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Field 'collection_id' doesn't have a default value
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 895
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 119
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 464
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 266
```

Comment: Why `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` and not `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: Asynchronous operations work better for me, I don't need to wait for inserts and raw performance is key.

Comment: How are you calling this code? Are you `await`ing it all the way up?

Comment: You should handle the `Application.ThreadException` event as well. I suspect that that will catch this exception. That's why execution would continue: the exception is thrown on a different thread.

Comment: \@Charlieface I am yes, even programs main is an async task.

Comment: @jmcilhinney There seems there is no ThreadException in console applications, all handled under the unhandled handler which I've set.

Comment: @user231071 Looking for SQL performace with single `INSERTS` + async C# is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but if the issue is still present or others face the same issue, I hope this can help with the solution.

I use `McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils` which may change the rules slightly, but still...

Wrapping `CommandLineApplication.Execute` with a try-catch works for me:

```cs
[Command(Name = "my-command", Description = "Handle commands")]
[HelpOption]
[Subcommand(typeof(MySubcommand))]
internal class Program
{
// ...

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {

        // ... other bootstrapping code, including setting up
        // the dbContext, a service provide, etc.

        try
        {
            return CommandLineApplication.Execute<Program>(args);
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            // Handle your error here
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private int OnExecute(CommandLineApplication app, IConsole console)
    {
        console.WriteLine("You must specify a subcommand");
        app.ShowHelp();
        return 1;
    }
}
```